# HTML stored in text field and not rendered in view

Tags: views

I'm trying to render HTML that's stored in a text field in a view. The output looks like this

```
<div class="wrapper">My text</div>
```

If I inspect it, it's wrapped in quotes so it's treated as a string. How do I parse this on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this, but you could try the [Simple Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter)